# Segfault on copying one std::string to another?

Tags: c++, oop, class, scope, segmentation-fault

I have the following class:

```
class StdinIo : public FileIo{
    public:
             StdinIo();
             ~StdinIo();

             static StdinIo* createObj(const std::string&);
             static bool     checkPath(const std::string&);
    private:
             std::string     tempPath;
             std::string     newPath();
};
```

Implementation 1:

```
StdinIo::StdinIo()
        :FileIo(newPath())
{    
}    
std::string StdinIo::newPath(){
        printf("%s Using FileIo\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
        std::stringstream tempPathStream;

        tempPathStream << tmpnam(NULL) << getpid();

        tempPathStream.flush();
        const char* szTempPath = tempPathStream.str().c_str();

        FILE *fp=fopen(szTempPath,"wb");
        size_t rv=1;
        char buffer[1024*8];
        if(fp){
                while(rv){
                        rv=fread(buffer,1,sizeof(buffer),stdin);
                        fwrite(buffer,1,rv,fp);
                }
                fclose(fp);
        }
        return tempPathStream.str();
}
```

Implementation 2:

```
StdinIo::StdinIo()
        :FileIo(newPath())
{    
}    
std::string StdinIo::newPath(){
        printf("%s Using FileIo\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
        std::stringstream tempPathStream;

        tempPathStream << tmpnam(NULL) << getpid();

        tempPathStream.flush();
        tempPath = tempPathStream.str();
        const char* szTempPath = tempPath.c_str();

        FILE *fp=fopen(szTempPath,"wb");
        size_t rv=1;
        char buffer[1024*8];
        if(fp){
                while(rv){
                        rv=fread(buffer,1,sizeof(buffer),stdin);
                        fwrite(buffer,1,rv,fp);
                }
                fclose(fp);
        }
        return tempPath;
  }
```

According to my knowledge of stack, Implementation 1 should give a segFault and Implementation 2 should not. But the reverse is happening. I am unable to figure out why.

I need the tempPath string as class member, so that I can delete the file later in the destructor.

```
StdinIo::~StdinIo(){
      if( unlink(tempPath.c_str()) != 0 )
              perror( "Error deleting file" );
}
```

After commenting out lines here and there, I have found that at the following line, seg-fault occurs:

```
 tempPath = tempPathStream.str();
```

gdb says:

```
 Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
 __exchange_and_add_dispatch (__mem=0xfffffffffffffff8, __val=<optimized out>)
     at /usr/src/debug/gcc-4.7.2-20120921/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/x86_64-redhat-          linux/libstdc++-v3/include/ext/atomicity.h:83
 83       return __exchange_and_add_single(__mem, __val);
```

Comment: @stardust_: `tempPath = tempPathStream.str();`

Answer (score 1):

Your second implementation calls `newPath()` and accesses `tempPath` (passing it to the base class constructor) before the object has been completely initialized. This results in undefined behavior.

If you absolutely need a local copy of the filename without making major changes to the existing code you can go with something like this using implementation #1.

```
class StdIoSpecialData : public FileIo
{
protected:

    StdIoSpecialData(const std::string &fname)
        : FileIo(fname),
          tempPath(fname)
    {
    }
    const std::string tempPath;
};

class StdIo : public StdIoSpecialData
{
public:
    StdIo()
       : StdIoSpecialData(newPath())
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: even if I write the statement: `tempPath =tempPathStream.str();` In Implementation 1 and return tempPathStream.str(); I get a seg-fault

Comment: Because you are accessing 'tempPath' and it hasn't been initialized yet. You are attempting to assign a string to an object that does not exist.

Comment: I've updated the question. @Captain Oblivious How do I initialize it?

Comment: Updated with a possible solution

Comment: I still don't understand what is the error in Implementation 2. I am first assigning a string to tempPath and then returning it. I am not accessing it without initializing it.